# asp.net - Attributes collection property

Tags: asp.net, attributes

What the Attributes collection property for ASP.NET controls/forms are used for?

Can we use this property for achieving the same functionality as RegisterStartupScript() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used for adding client-side attributes to a server-side control.  For instance:

```
ButtonSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure?');");
```

If you can get a reference to the HTML page's `body` tag, you should be able to do the same thing by adding an attribute like so:

```
BodyTag.Attributes.Add("onload", "myJavaScriptFunction();");
```

Comment: I modified my answer with a response.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes to a control that gets output as html.

So for this C# code:

```
ButtonSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure?');");
```

Something like this html will be output:

```
<input type="button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" value="Submit" />
```