# Asp.net controls' Attributes collection property

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239526/asp-net-attributes-collection-property) post of mine.

```
WebControl.Attributes.Add(string key, string value);
```

This is how `Attributes` property of an asp.net web control can be used.

Can anyone provide me with the complete list of `key`s that are available for use with web controls?

Any web link that contains the comprehensive list would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes are passed through directly to the rendered HTML, so the comprehensive list you are looking for is the W3C's documentation on HTML: [W3C's Index of HTML 4 Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/index/attributes.html)